# AArch64 Advanced SIMD assembly: operand 2 should be a SIMD vector register

Tags: gcc, arm, simd, neon, arm64

I want to multiply two 64-bits operand and simply put the result in a 128-bit SIMD vector in assembly. My operands are stored in two 128-bits vectors (`v0` and `v4`) and I want to multiply least significant half of `v4` with upper half of 'v0' and put the result into `v12`. For doing this, I came up with this syntax:

```
umull v12.2D, D1, D4
```

and base on ARM [documents](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1424433185653.html), I can map least significant and upper half of a vector using D register banks in advanced SIMD. But assembler gives me this error:

```
Error: operand 2 should be a SIMD vector register
```

I also tried to use vector indexing as follows:

```
umull v12.2D, v1.2s[1], v4.2s[0]
```

But I get the same error message.

Comment: Well, "D" is the scalar floating-point "double" view of the bottom half of a register, so yeah, it's not a SIMD vector - that would be [`v1.2S`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1427897596741.html). Either way there are no 64x64→128 operations (because there is no 128-bit type), so it seems like the whole premise of the question may be invalid.

Comment: @Notlikethat There are no 64x64 multiplication in AArch64? That means if I want to multiply two 64-bits operands, I should use four 32x32 multiplications? What is the difference between AArch64 and AArch32 then?

Comment: @Notlikethat from ARM v8 instruction set overview document we can write `umull Vd.<Td>, Vn.<Ts>, Vm.<Ts>`, where the <Td>/<Ts> can be 2D/2S. Isn't that 64x64 multiplication?

Comment: The source type is 2S, and the destination type is 2D, so no, it's a 32x32→64 multiplication. As it happens, [there's an exact summary of what's new in AArch64 NEON here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CEGDJGGC.html).

Comment: @A23149577: There is a 64x64 multiplication in AArch64, but not on SIMD registers; it operates on GPRs instead (N.B. the situation is exactly the same on x86_64; there's no 64-bit multiply on SSE/AVX registers).

Comment: @StephenCanon I cannot understand. In ARMv7 NEON we can compute two 32x32 multiplication simultaneously like `vmull.u32 Qd, Dn, Dm[0]`! That means `Dd = Dn[0] x Dm[0]' and 'Dd+1 = Dn[1] x Dm[0]`. Now I want to compute something like that in ARMv8 advanced SIMD which is supposed to give me better performance compare to ARMv7. How should I do that ? If there is only 32x32 multiplication available in AArch64 advanced SIMD, then the performance would be the same as AArch32. Is that correct?

Comment: @A23149577: The AArch64 ISA makes a lot of computations simpler and faster, but no ISA can magically provide a single instruction for every computation.  Presumably you computation doesn't consist solely of 64b multiplications; other portions of what you're doing most likely will benefit from AArch64.

Comment: @StephenCanon Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks a lot